# PHP is not returning version info on cmd prompt even though I have followed installations steps. How do I fix this?

Tags: php, installation, command-prompt

I recently decided to start learning PHP, and today I tried downloading PHP 8.1 on Windows, extracted the entire zip file into a new folder C:\php. I already added it to my PC's PATH through environment variables(it shows up).

I checked my version on cmd prompt multiple times but it keeps returning with this error msg:
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I looked at SO and other websites but they offer solutions that didn't work.

Comment: Did you restart the console? The environment variables (e.g. PATH) will take affect after you will close and start the console.

Comment: I did, I also tried restarting my computer but the same error message shows up.

Comment: I just tried that cmd, it returns 3 files and I'm not too sure what to make of it.  I downloaded directly from php.net, zip thread safe. I'm not sure which one that is or if it is even one of them.